# Redirect everything, except one subdomain

Tags: regex, .htaccess, subdomain

Everything has to redirect to www.domain.com. except for test.domain.com. Which will host a new version of the site for testing. 
both of the domains need to look within their web directory.

I've searched stack overflow but none of the similar questions seem to provide a working solution for me. Probably because I don't understand htacces / regex that well yet.

This is the current content of my .htacces file.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your second line (where test is your subdomain):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|test)\.
```

The ! negates the match.

The brackets are a regex group.

The pipe symbol is an or.

What this should say is "match me all subdomains except www. & test."

Regex101 link here which might help explain further and gives my test data:

https://regex101.com/r/5udsER/1/

**Disclaimer**:

I wrote this afk so this is lacking an end-to-end test but *should* work.